# Error using NavigationView / The app crashes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtime-error, navigation-drawer

I have use NavigationView on my app and now it starts crashing everytime I try to open it. I have searched a lot of questions similiar to this, but any solution works for me. I don't know how to solve it... I use the last version of Android Studio and the compileVersion is SDK 30.
This is the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: gladoop.javir3tics.test, PID: 18778
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gladoop.javir3tics.test/gladoop.javir3tics.test.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Binary XML file line #67: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Binary XML file line #67: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:651)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at gladoop.javir3tics.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler AbrirInicio in class gladoop.javir3tics.test.MainActivity
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:255)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:484)
2020-10-17 20:03:20.942 18778-18778/gladoop.javir3tics.test E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:531)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:207)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:129)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:367)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:235)
        at com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:122)
            ... 28 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: AbrirInicio [interface android.view.MenuItem]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1690)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:251)
            ... 35 more
```

My activity_main.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo_vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="418dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/fondo"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="49dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="412dp"
            android:layout_height="679dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-1dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="52dp">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/novedades"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="true"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/youtube"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/novedades"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="AbrirYouTube"
                android:src="@drawable/youtube" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:src="@drawable/twitch"
                android:layout_below="@id/youtube"
                android:id="@+id/twitch"
                android:onClick="AbrirTwitch"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/custom_appbar" />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/menu_iconos"
        android:background="@color/menu_lateral_fondo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_menu"
        app:itemIconPadding="15dp"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu">
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my MainActivity:

```
package gladoop.javir3tics.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    NavigationView menu;
    WebView mWebview;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        menu = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.menu_iconos);
        menu.setItemIconTintList(null);

        //WEB INICIO NOVEDADES


        mWebview = findViewById(R.id.novedades);
        WebSettings conf = mWebview.getSettings();
        conf.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mWebview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mWebview.loadUrl("https://gladoop.javiretics.me/novedades_inicio.html");
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                mWebview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });



        mWebview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }
        });


        // ONESIGNAL
        // Logging set to help debug issues, remove before releasing your app.
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);

        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();


    }






    // ABRIR DISTINTAS ACTIVIDADES


    public void AbrirInicio(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void AbrirYouTube(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YouTubeRSS_APP.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void AbrirInstagram(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Instagram.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void AbrirTwitter(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Twitter.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void AbrirTwitch(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Twitch.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void AbrirTikTok(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TikTok.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }







    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            onDestroy();
            System.exit(0);

        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pulsa otra vez para salir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    //Abrir Menu Lateral
    public void ToastMenu(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Desliza desde la izquierda para abrir el menú ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }



}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi by having a look at your logcat you can see that it gives you actual reason of your app crash which is this `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: AbrirInicio [interface android.view.MenuItem]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)` try to have a look into that once more and you'll find the main issue

Comment: But I have a correct method `public void AbrirInicio(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }`